# Update a second table based off of information I insert into another

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to update one table based off of information I place in another table.

What I am trying to do is insert a firstname into table1 and I want table2 to to insert that FirstName into it's table automatically based on the name placed into table1. Let's say I input the name john into table1 I want table2 to update it's FirstName column with the name john. How do I achieve this? and my second question is if I also Update the FirstName in Table 2 I want the FirstName in table1 to update with the "new" FirstName.

```
create table Table1 (
  TestOne int identity(1,1) primary key not null,
  FirstName nvarchar(50) not null,
);

create table Table2 (
  TestTwo int identity(1,1) primary key foreign key references Table1(TestOne) not null,
  FirstName nvarchar(50) not null,
);
```

Comment: use trigger [trigger guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Here's a question - why do you want to copy the same data from one table to another? Seems redundant. Surely the second table should just maintain a foreign key to the first. Then when you want to see both sets of data together you do a query which joins them. That's kind of the whole point of relational databases. Unless what you've shown here is an over-simplification, and you have some valid justification for creating copies of the same data, then I'm not sure this is the correct way to implement your schema.

Comment: The reason I am trying to copy data into a second table is that my original work "Not this example I have given" I have created a table where there is a customer details table, a customer invoice table. what I am trying to do is automatically have the customers details (Not just their name) inserted into the customer invoice table after the customer has placed their order. The example I gave above was simply constructed as a mean to understand the concept. thank you for asking that question. hopefully that makes things a little more clear.